# GMLib broken with Google Maps 3.27?

Tags: gmlib

Google release Google Maps API v.3.27 yesterday and GMLib appears to be broken.  When I specify v3 and the current release of the Google API (v3.27) is used, the map does not appear.  If I specify v.3.26 in my map.html, the application works correctly.

I am using GMLib 1.5.3 and the problem can be reproduced in the MegaDemo project included in the GMLib files.

Comment: Default. GMLib v1.5.3 uses the Maps API v3.17. Not tested on newer versions of this API and some properties of objects have been deleted

Comment: I understand, however according the Google Maps API documentation, they will retire a previous frozen version when a new one is introduced.  If you specify 3.17, it now uses 3.26.  At the next reelease (3.28), version 3.27 will be the frozen version and you won't have the option to use a version that works with the current version of GMLib.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#version-rollover-and-version-types

Comment: cadetill - is there a plan to address this issue?  Once Google releases 3.28 from experimental next month, the 3.27 version will be frozen and is the version the API will serve even if you specify 3.17 (or any other earlier version).  Users of GMLIB probably don't realize their map application will break.

Comment: I will try to up to date this week. However, you have the source code you can do it yourself ;-)

Comment: I started to take a look at this issue.  Do you have a recommended way to capture the console log from the twebbrowser?  Thanks.

Comment: Tested into 3.28 and work fine. I have update GMLib version on GitHub :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the newest version 1.5.4 from [here](https://github.com/cadetill/gmlib_v1)